# How to have hdd's auto-mounted and usable by all users?

Tags: fstab, automounting

My computer has 3 disk drives:

- 256GB ssd (root and swap partitions)
- 60GB ssd (ext4)
- 2TB hdd (ext4)

I want to automatically mount the two extra drives at boot and I want all users to be able to read/write/execute on them. To this end, I added the following lines to `fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1   /mnt/vertex ext4    defaults,users,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdc1   /mnt/cuda   ext4    defaults,users,noatime 0 0
```

From what I've read about `fstab`, I thought this should work but it doesn't. After rebooting or running `sudo mount -a`, the drives successfully mount but I cannot write to them as any user other than root.

Thinking this must because I created the dirs in `/mnt` as root, I created dirs in my home dir, and added these as the mount points in `fstab`. But the result is the same, at boot or by using `sudo mount -a`, the drives are mounted but cannot be written to without superuser privilege.

If I remove the lines from `fstab` and reboot, I can see the drives listed in my file manager (thunar). I can click on it and thunar will mount the drive, I can see the files on it, but I still cannot write to the drive.

I am lost.

Comment: Change the permissions of the mount point after the partitions are mounted (sorry for the previous deletion, was in the wrong window).

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do this every time I reboot/mount the drives? I'd like to avoid that if possible and just have them ready to go.

Comment: I just tested it with a USB drive, where the mount point doesn't even exist after the device is removed, and it worked fine. It's just like any other partition you mount.

Comment: I don't doubt that it works. I just don't want to run a `chown` command every time I log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two partitions are formatted as `ext4`, which by default sets the owner and group of the root dir of that volume to `root`, and permissions to `rwxrwxr-x` (IIRC). You can check that with

```
$ ls -la /mnt/<mountpoint>
```

In order to make them writable for normal users, you can either change the group of that root dir  to a common user's group with

```
$ sudo chgrp users /mnt/<mountpoint>
```

when the drive is mounted (replace the group name with an appropriate one), or you make that dir writeable for everyone (which may open a security gap):

```
$ sudo chmod o+w /mnt/<mountpoint>
```

This changes the volume's root dir's permissions (and only that) permanently, and needs to be done only once. Be aware that the owner, group and permissions of new FS entries (files, dirs etc.) still depend on the user that creates them. There are also more fine-grained possibilities to handle this, but that's an advanced topic and depends on your use-case. Extend this question or (better) create a new one if you have special requirements, and this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I was so focused on `fstab`, I forgot `chmod` was even an option.